# Why does the votingClassifier in sklearn.ensemble gives higher accuracy than each of the classifiers that make it? and should i depend on it?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model

I am running an ML classifier on my data.
I used SVM, RF and KNN. I used GScv for each of them and then used votingclassifier.The accuracy i got in each classifier independently was low, but from the hard and soft vote of the voting classifier is much higher! Why is that?

Here is my code

## Fitting Kernel SVM to training set

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(C=1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.005, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=1, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

## Checking accurancy, Best score of GV

```
print('Checking accurancy, Best score of GV')
best_accuracy =  grid_search.best_score_ 
print (best_accuracy)

[out] Checking accurancy, Best score of GV
0.5169491525423728
```

## Applying RandomForest (RF) Classification

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf_rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
clf_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf_rf.score(X_test, y_test)
print ("Mean accuracy is", (clf_rf.score(X_test, y_test)))

y_pred2 = clf_rf.predict (X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred2)

[out] accuracy 0.21
```

## Applying KNN

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train) 

print (neigh.score(X_train, y_train))

[out] accuracy 0.58
```

## Predicting the test set results

```
y_pred3 = neigh.predict (X_test)

from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

eclf1 = VotingClassifier (estimators= [('svm', clf), ('rf', clf_rf), ('KNN', neigh)], voting = 'hard')

eclf1 = eclf1.fit(X_train, y_train)

print 'Hard vote accuracy =', eclf1.score(X_train, y_train)


eclf2 = VotingClassifier (estimators= [('svm', clf), ('rf', clf_rf), ('KNN', neigh)], voting = 'soft')

eclf2 = eclf2.fit(X_train, y_train)

print 'Soft vote accuracy =', eclf2.score(X_train, y_train)

[out]
Hard vote accuracy = 0.9830508474576272
Soft vote accuracy = 0.7711864406779662
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I would say that your individual classifiers might be overfitting the training data. Ensemble voting is known to avoid overfitting, so it does not seem unlikely that the ensemble classifier behaves better than each classifier individually.

Comment: Could it be that the voting classifier is the overfit one and not doing a better job?

Comment: Matching several classifiers is expected to reduce the overfitting effect. In the worst case prediction, all classifiers are wrong, but the voting prediction is not worse than the individual ones.